# The usage of As + [ADJ]

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-usage

I came across some sentences in which they add as before a adjective, but I can't make it clear all the time, saying

> revising is more involved and typically means you've re-checked everything and made changes **as necessary**

and

> It is not really **as serious**.

In the above two instances. why do they add as? I think regardless of the first one, it is not really serious could make sense as well, as to the first one,  I am more confused about its meaning and usage.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these are actually idiomatic abbreviations for common expressions.

With the first example:  "As necessary" is an abbreviation for "as *is* necessary (to achieve some result)".  Examples:

> After running the race, make sure you drink as much water **as (is) necessary (for you to feel fully recovered).**
>
> Before you turn in your assignment, be sure to check it for completeness and accuracy.  Take as much time **as (is) necessary (to ensure there are no mistakes)**.

With the second example: There is a common grammatical structure that may be familiar to you, "as X as Y", used to relate something to something else, for example

> She is **as smart as a computer**

This is commonly used to relate an adjective to an opinion:

> The question isn't **as difficult as you might think.**

Your second example uses an *abbreviated* form of this structure.  As written the sentence is incomplete, and not grammatical, but nevertheless it would be commonly interpreted to mean something like:

> It's not really as serious **(as you might expect)**.

Again, in both these cases the missing parts should be easily understood from context.

Comment: I wonder if the last example was meant as "It's not really *that* serious." which doesn't require any addition.

Comment: @user3169  Sure, it could be "... not as serious (as something that is really serious)"  The context should give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

The first is a quasi-predicative **as**

Apply as [is] necessary.

and the second is a comparative **as** with the comparand supplied by earlier context:

It is not as serious (as something else).

P.S. **as is necessary** or **as necessary** is not a "sentence" but a subordinate clause, with **as** as the conjunction.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a clue why we can say as much as is necessary. Is as is necessary a whole sentence coz I cant break it down according to grammatical rules. I have seen some sentences like as were you, but it has a you as a subject here.

Comment: Please see the P.S.

Comment: I can see as is a conjunction, but can a subordinate clause be there without a whole sentence structure?

Comment: @Young: You have given complete sentences in your examples. They are not sentence fragments.  And I have given complete sentences in my examples as well.

Comment: Yeah. For my instance, it is a complete sentence, but in the phrase, saying as usual, as necessary, they are more like kind of sentence fragments,but as here is as a conjunction, after a conjunction is normally a complete sentence, so why I can use a conjunction and just a adjective follow it.

Comment: In some subordinate clauses, the verb-to-be (`BE`) is understood to be present or implicit, as in **as [is] necessary** or **as [may be] necessary**. This phenomenon occurs frequently with **as**.   *Take one or two pills for pain, **as needed***.